# Expanding textarea script does not work if is defined the height of textarea

Tags: javascript

This is my script:

```
function expandtext(textArea){ 
while (
    textArea.rows > 1 &&
    textArea.scrollHeight < textArea.offsetHeight
){
    textArea.rows--;
}
var h=0;
while (textArea.scrollHeight > textArea.offsetHeight && h!==textArea.offsetHeight)
{
    h=textArea.offsetHeight;
    textArea.rows++;
}
textArea.rows++
 }
```

Html:

```
<textarea class="expta" onkeyup="expandtext(this);" style="overflow-y:hidden;"></textarea>
```

So far everything works fine. But when I add textarea height:

```
<textarea class="expta" onkeyup="expandtext(this);" style="height:16px;overflow-y:hidden;"></textarea>
```

it does not work anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to explicitly set height of your textarea, you have to manipulate the `.height` property, not the `.rows`

Comment: I have manipulated the height property: style="height:16px;", not rows...

Comment: I mean, manipulating height property in your script.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the style-height- property for the textarea, this style property remains set to 16px until you manipulate this.

you need to change the textarea.style.height in your script instead of textarea.rows!

Comment: tried to set textArea.style.height = "16px"; but it does not work either.

Comment: of course, you need to manipulate it in every iteration step of your code